# Regex in Javascript without lookbehind to find a number surrounded by @

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find out the numbers (only numbers should match) in a string. The numbers to be identified are only those which are surrounded by '@'

So in string `'@432432@Hi@534543534@'` only `432432` and `534543534` should be retrieved.

I tried a regex but it uses look behind which is not supported in javascript (esp. in firefox). Thus looking for a compatible pattern.

The one I used is like the following:-

```
var str = '@432432@Hi@534543534@';
var list = str.match(/(?<=@)(\d{1,100})(?=@)/g)
```

//list is ['432432', '534543534']

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `str.match(/@(\d+)(?=@)/g).map(function(x) {return x.substr(1);})`, or [collect group 1 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) while running `RegExp#exec` within a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead and a capturing group instead:

`@(\d+)(?=@)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BE6XP2/1/)

```js
const regex = /@(\d+)(?=@)/g;
const str = `@432432@Hi@534543534@`
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: But then it selects the first (preceding) @ character

Comment: The following digits after the `@` are in the first capturing group.